# findeViewById returns null

Tags: android

I'm trying to build a simple Maps app based on the hello map tutorial but the `MapView` obtained with `findViewById` returns null. However, the map is shown properly in the emulator. So the app works, but I can't retrieve the map view in the code. What am I missing?

Code:

```
public class HelloMapActivity extends MapActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        if (mapView == null) {
            Log.d("onCreate", "map is null"); //log shows that mapView is null
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="the key"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setContentView(R.layout.main)` must be added before your `MapView`.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        if (mapView == null) {
            Log.d("onCreate", "map is null"); //log shows that mapView is null
        }
    }
```

I recommend to you add `setContentView` always immediately after you call
`super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`.

Answer (score 4):

`setContentView(R.layout.main);` should be come `before` `MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);`

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         setContentView(R.layout.main); //<----------------------------------------

        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        if (mapView == null) {
            Log.d("onCreate", "map is null"); //log shows that mapView is null
        }

    }
```